# Jquery click event hides div

Tags: jquery, css, refresh, hide

I am trying to refresh date on click of a div and I am not sure why div become invisible on clicking refresh. How can I refresh date on clicking div.
[JS fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mwLym/)

```
Jquery code

var monthId = (new Date).getMonth();
var dayNo=(new Date).getDate();
var monthName = GetMonthFullName(monthId);
var hours = new Date().getHours();
var minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
var orderDate = monthName +  " " + dayNo +", "+ hours +":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
function GetMonthFullName(monthNumber) {
      var months = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
      return months[monthNumber-1]
    }
$('#datetime').text(orderDate);
$('#refreshDetails').click(function(){    
$('#datetime').text(orderDate);
$("#detailsRefreshCont").load(location.href + "#detailsRefreshCont > *");
});



 HTML Code    

<div class="linkText" id="detailsRefreshCont" >
 <span id="datetime">  

 </span> 
 <span class="linkText" id="refreshDetails">Refresh</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use .load() there, try

```
//move the logic to a function so that it can be resused
function getTime() {
    var monthId = (new Date).getMonth();
    var dayNo = (new Date).getDate();
    var monthName = GetMonthFullName(monthId);
    var hours = new Date().getHours();
    var minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
    var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();

    return monthName + " " + dayNo + ", " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}

function GetMonthFullName(monthNumber) {
    var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    return months[monthNumber - 1]
}
$('#datetime').text(getTime());

$('#refreshDetails').click(function () {
    //there is no need to use load here, just call the function which returns the time
    $('#datetime').text(getTime());
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Bb57Z/)

In your case you are trying to reload the contents of the container element, which is failing thus the contents of the element `detailsRefreshCont` is emptied.

Comment: I have a jquery ajax call inside div. I removed it in this demo. I am trying to refresh div with load which calls controller and gets json data, empty div and bind data to div on every refresh.

Comment: @Chandana in that case try `$('#detailsRefreshCont').on('click', '#refreshDetails', function () {
        $("#detailsRefreshCont").load(location.href + " #detailsRefreshCont > *", function () {
            $('#datetime').text(getTime());
       `